# Xml file creation

Tags: c#, xml

i need help with my elements as i want to make sure that my file matches the elements and attributes below

```
<employees><employee><employeeId>employeeid</employeeId>
<hireDate>Hiredate</hireDate>
</employee>
<employee>
<employeeId>employeeid</employeeId>
<hireDate>Hiredate</hireDate>
</employee>
<employees>

<staffingHours processType="merge">

<staffHours>
<employeeId>employeeid</employeeId>
<workDays>
<workDay>
<date>date</date>
<hourEntries>
<hourEntry>
<hours>hours</hours>
<jobTitleCode>titlecode</jobTitleCode>
<payTypeCode>paycode</payTypeCode>
</hourEntry></hourEntries>
</workDay>
</workDays>
</staffHours>
</staffingHours>
```

Keep in mind that i am getting this data from an excel sheet on a web page and below is the code that generates the xml file  and i am using a for each loop from the gridview record

```
 XmlElement Empoyees = xmldoc.CreateElement("Employees");

    XmlElement newDept = xmldoc.CreateElement("Employee");
    XmlElement NurseId = xmldoc.CreateElement("employeeid");
    newDept.AppendChild(NurseId);
    NurseId.InnerText = row.Cells[0].Text;

    XmlElement Firstname = xmldoc.CreateElement("Firstname");
    newDept.AppendChild(Firstname);
    Firstname.InnerText = row.Cells[1].Text;
    //Second node and data source
    XmlElement Lastname = xmldoc.CreateElement("Lastname");
    newDept.AppendChild(Lastname);
    Lastname.InnerText = row.Cells[2].Text;

    //Third node and data source
    XmlElement Starthour = xmldoc.CreateElement("StartDate");
    newDept.AppendChild(Starthour);
    Starthour.InnerText = row.Cells[5].Text;
    //Fourth node and data source
    XmlElement EndDate = xmldoc.CreateElement("EndDate");
    newDept.AppendChild(EndDate);
    EndDate.InnerText = row.Cells[6].Text;

    XmlElement TotalHours = xmldoc.CreateElement("TotalHours");
    newDept.AppendChild(TotalHours);
    TotalHours.InnerText = row.Cells[10].Text;

    XmlElement Starttime = xmldoc.CreateElement("Starttime");
    newDept.AppendChild(Starttime);
    Starttime.InnerText = row.Cells[11].Text;

    XmlElement EndTime = xmldoc.CreateElement("EndTime");
    newDept.AppendChild(EndTime);
    EndTime.InnerText = row.Cells[12].Text;

    //Fourth node and data source
    XmlElement HireDate = xmldoc.CreateElement("HireDate");
    newDept.AppendChild(HireDate);
    HireDate.InnerText = row.Cells[8].Text;
    //write to the xml document
    xmldoc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(newDept, xmldoc.DocumentElement.LastChild);
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  Java?  C#?

Comment: i am using C# and VS2017

Comment: Why do you need help? What is wrong with the code you've pasted?

Comment: The way the xml comes out is not the way i wanted to be if you analyse the code it does not create the xml in the format i shared on top of this post.

Comment: No one's going to mentally compile your code (given they can't *actually* compile it due to the dependencies). Make it easy for someone to help you: provide a [mcve] that can be used to demonstrate your problem and include the current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this figured out in case someone need help on this see below

```
XmlElement employee = xmlDoc.CreateElement("employee");
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(employee);
Employees.AppendChild(employee);
//create the element
XmlElement NurseId1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("EmployeeID");
employee.AppendChild(NurseId1);
    NurseId1.InnerText = row.Cells[0].Text;

    XmlElement HireDate1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hireDate");
    employee.AppendChild(HireDate1); 
    DateTime newdate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[6].Text, fromFormat, null); 

    HireDate1.InnerText = newdate.ToString(toFormat);//row.Cells[6].Text;
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(Employees, xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild);

    }

    // Create a new <Employees> element and add it to the root node
    XmlElement staffHours = xmlDoc.CreateElement("staffHours");
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(staffHours);
    parentNode.AppendChild(staffHours);
    // Save to the XML file
    // Create a new <Employees> element and add it to the root node
    XmlElement WorkDays = xmlDoc.CreateElement("childElement");
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(WorkDays);
    staffHours.AppendChild(WorkDays); 

    XmlElement WorkDay = xmlDoc.CreateElement("mainchild");
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(WorkDay);
     WorkDays.AppendChild(WorkDay);

    XmlElement hourEntries = xmlDoc.CreateElement("subchild");
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(hourEntries);
    WorkDay.AppendChild(hourEntries);

    XmlElement HourEntry = xmlDoc.CreateElement("childsub");
    xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(HourEntry);
    hourEntries.AppendChild(HourEntry);

//First node and data source
XmlElement NurseId = xmlDoc.CreateElement("mainelement");
staffHours.AppendChild(NurseId);
NurseId.InnerText = row.Cells[0].Text;

//Third node and data source
XmlElement Date = xmlDoc.CreateElement("date");
WorkDay.AppendChild(Date);
DateTime converteddate = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[1].Text, fromFormat, null);
Date.InnerText = converteddate.ToString(toFormat); 

XmlElement newDept = xmlDoc.CreateElement("childmain");
//Fourth node and data source
XmlElement Hours = xmlDoc.CreateElement("hours");
HourEntry.AppendChild(Hours);
Hours.InnerText = row.Cells[2].Text;

XmlElement starthour = xmlDoc.CreateElement("starthour");
HourEntry.AppendChild(starthour);
starthour.InnerText = row.Cells[9].Text;

XmlElement Lunch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Lunch");
HourEntry.AppendChild(Lunch);
Lunch.InnerText = row.Cells[11].Text;

XmlElement endhour = xmlDoc.CreateElement("endhour");
HourEntry.AppendChild(endhour);
endhour.InnerText = row.Cells[10].Text;

XmlElement JobTitleCode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("JobTitleCode");
HourEntry.AppendChild(JobTitleCode);
JobTitleCode.InnerText = row.Cells[3].Text;

XmlElement payTypeCode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("payTypeCode");
HourEntry.AppendChild(payTypeCode);
payTypeCode.InnerText = row.Cells[4].Text;

xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(parentNode, xmlDoc.DocumentElement.LastChild);
 catid = row.Cells[0].Text;
}
```